# when order of product of two commuting elements in $p$-group is lcm?

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups

Let $G$ be an abelian $p$-group, and $a,b\in G$. Then the order of $ab$ *divides* the l.c.m. of orders of $a$ and $b$; it is not necessarily equal.

**Question:** *What is (are) the necessary and sufficient condition(s) on $a,b$ so that  $o(ab)$ will be the l.c.m. of order $o(a)$ and $o(b)$?*

Certain obvious sufficient conditions are

- $\langle a\rangle \cap \langle b\rangle =\{1\}$
- or $\langle a\rangle\nsubseteq \langle b\rangle$ (or viceversa).

I want to see an exact necessary and sufficnent condition on $a$, $b$ with above requirement.